# "unused argument" error for "name_repair" parameter in read_csv()

Tags: r

I tried to run the following code:

```
read_csv("../../../../../../Downloads/archive (1)/fish.csv", name_repair = make.names)
```

The following error message appeared:

```
Error in read_csv("../../../../../../Downloads/archive (1)/fish.csv",  : 
  unused argument (name_repair = make.names)
```

I know that the path is valid as the code ran fine without the second argument `name_repair`. Does anyone have an idea as to why it wouldn't be working? The argument itself is correct as it worked for my professor.

Comment: I just tested on a local CSV and it worked okay for me. Can you try specifying `readr::read_csv(...)` to make sure you're getting the right version of the function? And what version of `readr` do you have installed?

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$readr$Version` return for you? And what about `environment(read_csv)`?